# Swift: Silence Log

Tags: ios, swift, image

In my code I'm checking a lot of time if an image/asset exists with:

```
if let myImage = UIImage(named: ext) {
      cell.mySymbol.image = myImage
}
```

Every time I'm checking hundreds of strings. Every time an asset is not found, I'm getting this error in the log/debug area:

```
2018-06-30 21:24:17.989924+0200 myProject[2945:86150] [framework] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: ''
```

Those errors make it nearly impossible to debug the errors that are important for me.

**Is there a way to either silence those logs/errors or is there another way of checking if an asset exists?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your error doesn't appear when the image not exist , it appear when u try to check for empty string ""

just check if the string is empty before calling UIImage.init

```
if !ext.isEmpty, let myImage = UIImage(named: ext) {
    cell.mySymbol.image = myImage
}
```

Comment: No the string isn't empty. Even if I use this `if (UIImage(named: ext) != nil) && (ext.isEmpty == false)` it still outputs the error

Comment: `if (ext.isEmpty == false) && (UIImage(named: ext) != nil)` works too. `(ext.isEmpty == false) ` just needs to be checked first, but thanks for your help